# Localizing MVC 3 client side validation messages

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, localization

I'm working on an ASP.Net MVC 3 project, which needs localized error messages from its validation rules.

Is there any way to do this client side ?

I can live with english serverside validation messages, as the client side ones should always be triggered (I've no fear my users will disable javascript, as it's an Intranet site)

Whilst I can use DataAnnotations for stuff such as [Required] and [StringLength], there is no such option (it seems) for data type validation.

If for instance I have int Portions in my view model, it's automatically validate input to ensure it's an int. Fair enough, but the validation message is always in english :-(

Suppose my model looks like this:

```
public class RecipeModel
{

[Display(Name = "Navn")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Skal udfyldes")]
public string Name { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Portioner")]
public int Portions { get; set; }

}
```

As you can see I have a custom errormessage for "Name", however if I try to enter text into the EditorFor(Portions), it'll show my this errormessage:

"The field Portioner must be a number."

And that's the errormessage I want to localize. Unfortunately there's no DataAnnotation for that built-in validator (checking that it's an int).

I even tried using a DataType annotation of type Custom, to no avail :-(

Comment: How are you validating? With asp validators? If so you should be able to amend the validator with the localised message when rendering the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own validation messages using data annotations with your model. If you want to support multiple languages you can create a resource file for each language and link from the data annotation to the Id of the message in your resource file.

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to mention what kind of validation troubles me. I'm updating the question.

Comment: You can change the default English validation messages. Look at the "ErrorMessage" parameter in the Required attribute.

Comment: Yes i realize that, it's how to chance the validation message for data typen, such as int, dates and so forth. Sorry if my question was too unclear :-/

Comment: All the standard validation attributes have an ErrorMessage that can be customized.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately the datatype validation happens solely based on the actual datatype (int, DateTime, etc.) - that is, without any data annotations. I'll add some code to the question, hopefully that'll clarify it better.